# Video cards DirectX support

Tags: graphics-card, directx

If a video card specs say it supports DirectX 12 does it necessarily mean that DirectX 11 is supported?
I know this may sound stupid but i want to make sure before buying fancy expensive video card to find out later that it is not suitable.
Thanks

Comment: This is easily researchable. `DirectX 12` is an update to `DirectX 11.x`.

Comment: I know that it's an upgrade to Direct X 11, and I Know Windows 7 uses Direct X 11 by default but not all video cards supports Direct X 11, that's why I am asking about this.

Comment: I will say it another way.  All `DirectX 12` hardware support to run `DirectX 9`, `DirectX 10`, DirectX and 11.x software also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectX is part hardware, part software solution. On one hand downward compatibility is assumed to be there, on the other this may sometimes not be a case. But this is related to software side overwhelmingly.

So basically you can safely assume new, fancy card you buy will be able to work with older software. However, this is based on the - unspoken - assumption you run one of the newer Windows versions (anything after Vista)... Because if you don't you may face some issues. But again, those are mainly with anything older than DirectX10.